Sticky sessions in kubernetes behind Nginx and backend (not in ingress)
Can I connect to specific pod of deployment without using a service (clusterIP)?
We have a deployment of nginx and an another deployment of backend. And we need to realize sticky sessions. For non-kubernetes deployments it will looks like
  upstream sticky-app {
        hash $cookie_key;
        server backend1:80;
        server backend2:80;
    }

But what should I do in kubernetes if backend1 and backend2 are pods of one deployment? I can access them by service that is resolved as single IP address, and as I know services don’t provide any mechanism for sticky sessions.

Maybe you want a headless service? The DNS result for a headless service is a list of individual pod ip addresses. You would need to translate that into an appropriate configuration. It looks like that should pretty much just work, see e.g. this article.
